# How to obscure a password in OSGi Felix component property?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I've got an OSGi component, declared with an annotation, that allows a login credential property to be configured through Felix's configuration UI. I've seen other components that obscure a property text field for passwords, but mine is still in the clear. I'd assume that there is just a flag that is included in the @Property annotation, but I can't find any mention of it in the [documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#property).

Does anyone know how to create a password field in the configuration UI?

Comment: This sounds like a bad (very insecure) idea.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd say that. Felix's config UI is already locked down to admin users. And it needs to be configured to pass credentials to other servers (databases, ldap, etc.). This simply makes it so that someone looking over the admin's shoulder doesn't see the passwords as they are entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a annotation property that can be used:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = StringUtils.EMPTY;
private String username = DEFAULT_USERNAME;
@Property(label="username", description="user name", value=DEFAULT_USERNAME )
public static final String USERNAME = "xxx.username";

private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = StringUtils.EMPTY;
private String password = DEFAULT_PASSWORD;
@Property(label="password", description="user password", passwordValue=DEFAULT_PASSWORD )
public static final String PASSWORD = "xxx.password";
```

Notice that the `USERNAME` constant is being annotated with the `value` parameter, where as `PASSWORD` is annotated with `passwordValue` parameter. It is the use of `passwordValue` that triggers the field to be obscured in the OSGi console.

Answer (score 1):

The OSGi Metatype Service Specification does support a [PASSWORD](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r5/cmpn/org/osgi/service/metatype/AttributeDefinition.html#PASSWORD) attribute type which should be used by UIs to obscure the text field.

Furthermore, in Declarative Services, property names which start with full stop (e.g. `.password`) will not be published as service properties on any component which is a service. The property is available in the component properties.

Comment: But is the `PASSWORD` attribute type available from the declarative service? I've only used the declarative approach. Mixing declarative with whatever config file I'd need to bundle to configure this as a password field seems like a lot of work. Also the "full stop" functionality I think is met by the declarative `propertyPrivate` attribute. (I was hoping that would make it a password field, but it just hides it in the UI.)